# Python assignment quirk w/ list index assign, dict index assign, and dict.get

Tags: python, ruby, variable-assignment

In ruby 2.4:

```
x = ['a']
y = {}
x[0] = y[x[0]] = y.fetch(x[0], y.length)
puts y #=> {"a"=>0}
```

In python 3.5:

```
x = ['a']
y = {}
x[0] = y[x[0]] = y.get(x[0], len(y))
print(y) #=> {0: 0}
```

Why this?

ETA:

```
y[x[0]] = x[0] = y.get(x[0], len(y))
```

produces expected behavior (much to my chagrin.)

Comment: Because Python and Ruby are different languages? Python assigns to a series of assignment targets from left to right, Ruby from right to left.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sufficiently counterintuitive semantics are indistinguishable from compiler bugs.

Comment: I find assignment expressions to be abhorrent, so we appear to be at an impasse. Pick a different language?

Comment: Please stop moving the goal posts. If you have follow-up questions, make a new post.

Comment: You should ask one question per question, if you have other questions then you should ask as a new question with what you have tried and researched.

Comment: despite `x[0] = y[x[0]] = y.fetch(x[0], y.length)` being valid and yielding the *expected* results in Ruby, do you people write code like that? That is massively convoluted..

Comment: And again, take the right-hand side expression, evaluate that, then assign from left to right. Your last edit would only produce `{None: 0}` if `x[0]` was `None`, not `'a'`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The code in question replaces sensitive data ids with non-sensitive numeric ids, in-place. Lookup sensitive id, replace with numeric if not seen before, replace in data row. I've been coding for 10 years and I have a BA degree in CS.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen I am just saying it looks *very* error prone and *very* difficult to read. But if you feel comfortable with it..

Comment: "x at zero and y at x-zero both get y at x-zero or cardinality y if y does not have zero"

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen *"..if y does not have **x-zero**"*

Comment: @Ev.Kounis No, no sane Ruby developer would write this kind of convoluted code. Chained assignments usually looke like `x = y = z = 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby and Python are different languages, and make different choices. In Python assignments are *statements* and evaluates multiple assignment targets from *left to right*. Ruby made other choices; assignments are *expressions* and as a result are evaluated in the opposite order.

So in Ruby this happens:

- Evaluate `y.fetch(x[0], y.length)`, produces `0` (key is missing, `y` is empty).
- Evaluate `y[x[0]] = 0`, so `y['a'] = 0`. This is an expression resulting in `0`.
- Evaluate `x[0] = 0` (`0` being the result of the `y[x[0]] = 0` assignment expression).

Note that in Ruby, an assignment is an *expression*. It can be nested inside other expressions, and the result of the assignment expression is the value of the target after assignment.

In Python this happens instead:

- Evaluate `y.get(x[0], len(y))`, produces `0` (key is missing, `y` is empty).
- Evaluate `x[0] = 0`.
- Evaluate `y[x[0]] = 0`, so `y[0] = 0`.

From the Python [assignment statements documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

So the expression on the right-hand-side is evaluated *first*, and then assignment takes place to each target from left to right.

Python made assignments statements on purpose, because the difference between:

```
if a = 42:
```

and

```
if a == 42:
```

is so damn hard to spot, and even if intentional really hurt the readability of code. In Python, readability counts. A lot.

Generally speaking, you really want to avoid making assignments to names that are then also used in subsequent assignments in the same statement. Don't assign to `x[0]` and then use `x[0]` again in the same assignment, that's just hugely confusing.

Comment: But... That goes against C?! And it makes it impossible to transcribe it into __setitem__ calls directly! Madness!

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: Why is that madness? Why should all languages make the same choice here?

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: and of course this is translatable to to `__setitem__` calls. You just need to adjust your evaluation order.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: And most importantly: assignments in Python are statements, in C and Ruby they are expressions. That's a huge philosophical difference right there.

Comment: Chained assignments explicitly emulate C. To deviate from C's behavior is to violate the principle of least surprise. It is definitionally unpythonic. Make it a hard error or emulate C.

Comment: Also `y[x[0]] = x[0] = y.get(x[0], len(y))` does _not_ do what I want it to do.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: you can try to take that up with the Python developers on `python-ideas@python.org`. Python is **not C**. Again, in C assignments are **expressions**, not statements. It is extremely Pythonic, because that's how the language was designed.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: Python doesn't use `&&` and `||` either, it uses `and` and `or`. We use indentation to delineate blocks, not curly braces. Etc. Why should Python stick to other conventions the language designer feels hurt readability and maintainability?

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: and why does `y[x[0]] = x[0] = y.get(x[0], len(y))` not do what you want it to do? That's exactly what you wanted the Ruby expression to do, assign to `y[x[0]]` *first* before `x[0]` is changed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Your Ruby description could be improved. `y[x[0]] = 0` is evaluated : `y['a']` is set to `0`, and this assignment returns `0`. `x[0] = y[x[0]]` _isn't_ evaluated. `x[0] = 0` is. As in `x[0] = ( y[x[0]] = ( y.fetch(x[0], y.length) ) )`

Comment: @MartijnPieters if python is pythonic by definition, then we cannot discuss the pythonicness of python features. What I am saying is that python goes against the grain for poorly explained reasons, when it could just as easily mimic C: no need for actual assignment expressions, but can we have the multi assignment proceed in the same order as literally every other programming language? What is surprising is that python goes against the grain. That is not very pythonic.

Comment: @EricDuminil: yes, that's indeed what I meant. Thanks for going over it, I'll update it.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: *Pythonic* is a very subjective term anyway, but when the language has made an explicit decision to make assignments statements, and not expressions, *because* it fits the 'readability counts* principle better, then that's an argument that it is Pythonic. It is Pythonic because that's the proper Python way to see assignments.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: again, it is only common in programming languages where assignment is an expression; the *result* of th expression is the newly assigned value, which then feeds into the next assignment. Right-to-left is natural there because of that relationship. Left to right is natural everywhere else. Also see [*Chained assignment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Chained_assignment) on wikipedia, where the right-to-left variant is classified as *some programming languages*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right-associative assignment: C, C#, C++, D, Rust, Ruby, PHP, Java, Javascript, Go, Perl, Swift, Scala. Not: Lisps (no assignment operator), Lua (disallowed by syntax), Haskell (disallowed by type system), SML (disallowed by type), OCaml (disallowed by type), Python (left associative???). There is no pattern, there is no good rationale other than 'let's be different!'.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: You named a series of languages that made assignment *an expression*, yes. The other examples all don't allow chained assignment. We can go on and on arguing about this, but it'd be far more productive for you to take your torch up with the Python core developers on [Python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas). Be prepared to bring better arguments than just 'all these languages do it this way' without acknowledging that they are forced into that ordering by the grammar choice, and show how adhering to that convention would be better for Python.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen: And Python **is not left associative** here. There is no association order because assignment is a **statement**, not an expression. Expressions are associative, statements are not.